# How to use the variables from karate-config.js to .feature files

Tags: karate

I am new to use the Karate DSL framework in all the demo examples in the https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo the url is given as demoBaseUrl from where this URL is getting, if it is getting from karate-config.js then how it is used in the .feature file and how to define those variable in the karate-config.js as well

When the karate-config.js file will be executed if we run any testSuite and when those variables will be used in the .feature files

Below is the code which am I using

### .feature file:

Feature: Simple users test script

```
Background:
```

* url baseUrl

Scenario: get all users and validate the response

Given path 'users'
When method get
Then status 200

### .js file:

```
function()
```

{
    var baseUrl= 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

}

After execution this is exception I am getting:

Scenario: [1:6]get all users and validate the response
Test 1 : * url baseUrl 0.004878
-unknown-:4 - javascript evaluation failed: baseUrl, ReferenceError: "baseUrl" is not defined in  at line number 1

Comment: Make sure you are using Java 8 as runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

Please take the help of someone who knows JS. Your config file should be:

```
function(){ return { baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' } }
```

Comment: 1.Hi Peter thanks for the response, I tried with the code which you mentioned to provide in the config file but its not working, the test suite is not even starting its execution.
2.For executing environment wise should I provide the env variables only in config file or else in any other file

Comment: @raghuveer please follow this process now, thanks https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue